# How can I search the specific value in the _source from elasticSearch inquired result?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm collecting logs through Elastic Search. And I look up the results through a query.

When inquiring with the following query

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all":{
    }
  }
}
```

The result is inquired as follows.

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 100,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_id" : "1a2b3c4d5e6f",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "team" : "Marketing"
          "number" : "3"
          "name" : "Mark"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_id" : "1a2b3c4d5e66",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "team" : "HR"
          "number" : "1"
          "name" : "John"
        }
      }, 
      ........
```

but, I want to be inquired as below.(Specific value of Inner_hits)

```
{
    "name": "Mark"
},
{
    "name": "John"
},
```

So, How can I query a specific value inner_hits?

Thanks.

Comment: Inner hits can be used by defining an `inner_hits definition` on a nested, `has_child` or `has_parent` query and `filter`. Can you please share your index mapping and expected search result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the [source_filtering feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-source-filtering.html) of ES, so in your case, your query will like below:

```
{
    "_source": "name",
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

And it returns search results like

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "64214413",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Mark"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "64214413",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "John"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: According to the current results, there are many values in json format such as _index,_type, etc.

Is it possible to store the "name" in the variable in inner_hits?

Comment: I'm sorry it's too late. I was hospitalized for an accident. After I was discharged from the hospital, I logged in with my Facebook ID and did activities.(This ID was linked to git)
It's late, but thank you so much for your reply.